# Which of these two operators is an orthogonal projection?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

Which of these two operators on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is an orthogonal projection? $T(f(x)) = f(|x|)$ or $S(f(x))= f(-|x|)$? Should I use the definition (which I tried and failed at) or some other sufficient condition?

Comment: It would be better to write $(Tf)(x)=f(|x|)$ because $T$ maps a function to a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me like the answer is neither. We see that the image of both $S$ and $T$ is equal to the subspace of even functions (for any even function $g$, we have $Tg=Sg=g$, and clearly, the image of $T$ and $S$ consists of even functions).

Let $Uf(x)=\frac{f(|x|)+f(-|x|)}{2}$ and note that for even $g$, we have
$$
\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^0 f(x)\overline{g}(x)\textrm{d}x+\int_0^{\infty} f(x)\overline{g}(x)\textrm{d}x=\int_0^{\infty} (f(x)+f(-x))\overline{g}(x)\textrm{d}x=\langle Uf,g\rangle,
$$
where the last equality follows from the same calculation since $Uf(x)+Uf(-x)=f(x)+f(-x)$. Again, it's clear that $U$ is a projection onto the space of even functions. From the above, it follows that $U$ is the orthogonal projection onto this space. However, $U$ is neither equal to  $T$ nor $S$.

Concretely, consider the $L^2$ functions  $f_1(x)=1_{x\leq -1}\frac{1}{x}$ and $f_2=1_{x\geq 1} \frac{1}{x}$ and note that $Tf_1=S f_2=0,$ but we see that $f_1+f_2$ is even and
$$
\langle f_1,f_1+f_2\rangle=\langle f_2,f_1+f_2\rangle=1\neq0,
$$ 
so neither $T$ nor $S$ is an orthogonal projection.

Comment: I actually selected these two operators in a list, by excluding those who were not idempotent (but maybe I was wrong). Maybe you can tell me if one of these is an orthogonal projection instead: $T_1(f(x))= sgn(x)f(x)$; $T_2(f(x))= f(-x)$ ; $T_3(f(x))= f(x) + f(-x)$ ; $T_4(f(x))=f(\frac{x}{2})\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: $T_3$ is equal to $2U$, so it's almost correct. It's true that none of these are idempotent.

Comment: Ok, there's also another one which is idempotent $T_5(f(x)) = \chi_{x >0}f(-x)$ , where $\chi$ is the characteristic function. Maybe this is the projection, because it resembles the multiplication operator with a characteristic function, except for that minus sign...

Comment: It's not idempotent. $T_5^2=0$.

Comment: My bad, you're right. So $T_3$ could be the case?

Comment: Well.. again... as written... none of them are orthogonal projections, but $\frac{T_3}{2}$ is an orthogonal projection.